# Proof: Reverse triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

The [proof in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality) is straightforward just why have we come to the conclusion that
$$-\|x-y\|\leq\|x\|-\|y\|\leq \|x-y\|\Rightarrow abs( \|x\| -\|y\|)\leq \|x-y\|$$ and not $$\|x\|-\|y\|\leq abs( \|x-y\|)$$?

Comment: I am looking as $w=\|x\|-\|y\|$ and $\|x-y\|=5$ so $-5\leq w \leq 5\rightarrow |w|\leq 5$ and not $5\leq |w|$

Comment: $\|x-y\| \geq 0$, so taking the absolute value in your last inequality does nothing, so it can’t possibly be what you’re trying to prove.

Answer (score 2):

By the  triangle inequality $$\|x\|=\|(x-y)+y\|\le\|x-y\|+\|y\|,$$ so $\|x\|-\|y\|\le\|x-y\|$. Change the roles of $x,y$ to get $\|y\|-\|x\|\le\|x-y\|$. This finishes the proof.